# Retrieve LoggedOnUsers on Remote Machine

Tags: c#, wmi, wql

I'm building a C# application to monitor server and workstation workloads with WMI and WQL queries. I'm using WMI because it seems to be faster in comparison to powershell queries. My hardship starts when I try to retrieve logged on users on a remote machine. I figured I need to use the *Win32_LoggedOnUser* class. I have tried the following queries:

`@"SELECT * FROM Win32_LoggedOnUser"` 
`@"SELECT Antecedent FROM Win32_LoggedOnUser"`

What I'm used to is to retrieve the desired value like this:

```
var cims = connection.getCimInstances(this, queryUser);

 if (cims != null)
 {
    foreach (CimInstance cim in cims)
    {
      Komponenten.User user = new Komponenten.User();
      user.Name = Convert.ToString(cim.CimInstanceProperties["Name"].Value);
                    users.Add(user);
    }
 }
```

where *queryUser* is one of the strings from above.

In both cases, I get a *Win32_Account* object in return, which seems to suggest - and the debugger seems to confirm -  that I should use `CimInstanceProperties["Name"].Value` on the returned `Win32_Account` class again. But that's not working at all. Any ideas on how to get access to the CimInstanceProperties of a Win32_Account stored in a CimInstanceProperity ? I can't find anything on the respective Windows reference page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-loggedonuser) nor during my extensive google-search.

Thanks!

Comment: "But that's not working at all" what do you mean by that? when you created the connection (with username and password i guess) have you checked that the connection is ok?

Comment: Too fuzzy, agreed. The connection is ok, I also get the CimInstance-Object back, but the CimInstanceProperty  holds two new CimInstance-Objects (Antecedent and Descendent) which again have a CimInstanceProperty as member. I would like to access the properties of the Antecendent-Object, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the *ManagementObject-Class* and *Regex* to find the usernames after converting the *Antecedent* - Object to a string:

```
var users = new List<Komponenten.User>();
        var searcher = this.connection.makeQuery(this, "SELECT * FROM Win32_LoggedOnUser");

        if (searcher != null)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Komponenten.User user = new Komponenten.User();
                var win32_account = queryObj["Antecedent"].ToString();
                string stripped = Regex.Replace(win32_account, "[^a-zA-Z=]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
                int end = stripped.LastIndexOf("=");
                user.Name = stripped.Substring(end+1);
                users.Add(user);
            }

            this.users = users;
```

An alternative which takes the *LogonSession* into account is:

```
var users = new List<Komponenten.User>();
        var searcher = this.connection.makeQuery(this, "SELECT LogonId  FROM Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType=2");
        var Scope = this.connection.getScope(this, this.connection.getConnection());

        if (searcher != null)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                ObjectQuery LQuery = new ObjectQuery("Associators of {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=" + queryObj["LogonId"] + "} Where AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent");
                ManagementObjectSearcher LSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, LQuery);
                foreach (ManagementObject LWmiObject in LSearcher.Get())
                {
                    Komponenten.User user = new Komponenten.User();
                    user.Name =  Convert.ToString(LWmiObject["Name"]);
                    users.Add(user);
                }
            }
            this.users = users;
        }
```

where *this.connection.getConnection* is a *ConnectionsOption* object depending on your respective domain and account data